# Load concatenate link from form

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty concatenating input from a field into a link which is loaded when the user clicks submit.  My current code for the form looks like this:

```html
<form id="your_form">
  <input type="text" name="FPCAbundanceGroup" id="keywords" 
  onclick="location.href='https://meet.jit.si/FPCAbundanceGroup' + document.getElementById("keywords").value;">
  <p></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Join Group" >
</form>
```

the intention is to load the generated link into the current window.  This method works when I am not attempting to concatenate but fails when I do. Thanks in advance for taking a look.

Comment: see those double quotes around `"keywords"`... that's the issue use ... `'keywords'` for a better chance of working

Comment: That was extremely helpful.  I still needed to move the onclick to the submit but and change its type from submit to button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error. You're prematurely closing the onclick function by using quotation mark `"` with getElementById.  Only use `"` to start and end the function, use `'` for any other strings inside the function

It might also be good to escape the `//` in the link string:

```html
<input type="text" name="FPCAbundanceGroup" id="keywords" 
onclick="location.href='https:\/\/meet.jit.si/FPCAbundanceGroup' + document.getElementById('keywords').value;>"
```

Answer (score 1):

The form can do the get request without you having to change the location. Here I change the action attribute on the form each time the user writes something in the form field. The form will just do a get request to the url. Notice the form attribute on the input element has the value "none" (just a random value that does *not* refer to a form), so the value of the input element in not in the query string of the request.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  document.forms.form01.action = `https://meet.jit.si/FPCAbundanceGroup${e.target.value}`;
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="https://meet.jit.si/FPCAbundanceGroup" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="fpcabundancegroup" form="none">
  <input type="submit" value="Join Group">
</form>
```